# Zappa: UpdateFunctionConfiguration operation: The operation cannot be performed at this time. An update is in progress for resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, zappa

I am try update a lambda by zappa, I created virtualenv and active virtualenv and install libraries, but in the moment run zappa update enviroment, I have this problem:
How can i fix this :(

```
 zappa update qa
(pip 18.1 (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages), Requirement.parse('pip>=20.3'), {'pip-tools'})
Calling update for stage qa..
Downloading and installing dependencies..
Packaging project as zip.
Uploading maximo-copy-customers-qa-1637639364.zip (6.0MiB)..
100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 6.32M/6.32M [00:09<00:00, 664kB/s]
Updating Lambda function code..
Updating Lambda function configuration..
Oh no! An error occurred! :(

==============

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 2778, in handle
    sys.exit(cli.handle())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 512, in handle
    self.dispatch_command(self.command, stage)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 559, in dispatch_command
    self.update(self.vargs['zip'], self.vargs['no_upload'])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 979, in update
    layers=self.layers
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zappa/core.py", line 1224, in update_lambda_configuration
    Layers=layers
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 676, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.ResourceConflictException: An error occurred (ResourceConflictException) when calling the UpdateFunctionConfiguration operation: The operation cannot be performed at this time. An update is in progress for resource: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:937280411572:function:maximo-copy-customers-qa
```

Comment: I am also facing this error from yesterday. Seems like some change in AWS is causing this error.

Comment: I feel if we add `time.sleep` here, it should fix the issue https://github.com/ib-devs/Zappa/blob/apigateway_stages_multiple_routes_support/zappa/cli.py#L845

Comment: I can fix this problem upgrade zappa version and change python version inside virtual enviroment to 3.8

Answer (score 7):

I would add a more sophisticated solution what mentioned LiriB earlier. Use the aws lambda cli which has the function-updated command ([documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/wait/function-updated.html)).

Example:
`aws lambda wait function-updated --function-name "$FN_NAME"`

This command will wait until the function is updated. In case it is not upated in 5 minutes, it will stop the execution.

Answer (score 4):

You should wait for function code update to complete before proceeding with update of function configuration. Inserting the following shell script between the steps can keep the process waiting:

```
STATE=$(aws lambda get-function --function-name "$FN_NAME" --query 'Configuration.LastUpdateStatus' --output text)
while [[ "$STATE" == "InProgress" ]]
do
    echo "sleep 5sec ...."
    sleep 5s
    STATE=$(aws lambda get-function --function-name "$FN_NAME" --query 'Configuration.LastUpdateStatus' --output text)
    echo $STATE
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to your zappa_settings.json:

```
"lambda_description": "aws:states:opt-out"
```

[Zappa issue about it](https://github.com/zappa/Zappa/issues/1041)

Comment: I try it, but the error is the same.

Comment: try to put aws:states:opt-out at lambda description. 
go to the lambda -> configuration -> general configuration


link about it: https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/compute/coming-soon-expansion-of-aws-lambda-states-to-all-functions/

Comment: It's temporary plan